# Modify javascript object to specific format

Tags: javascript

```
let data = {
    "rec": [{
            "id": "25837",
            "contentId": "25838"
        },
        {
            "id": "25839",
            "contentId": "25838"
        },
        {
            "id": "25838"
        },
        {
            "id": "25636",
            "contentId": "25837"
        }, {
            "id": "25640",
            "contentId": "25839"
        }
    ]
};
```

I have a javascript object which I have to manipulate to below format.

```
{
    "childern": [{
        "id": "25838",
        "childern": [{
                "id": "25837",
                "contentId": "25838",
                "childern": [{
                    "id": "25636",
                    "contentId": "25837"
                }]
            },
            {
                "id": "25839",
                "contentId": "25838",
                "childern": [{
                    "id": "25640",
                    "contentId": "25839"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

If any object dont have `contentId` it should be at parent level. then all the objects having `contentId` same as parent id should be at its child level and so on.

I have created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/imjaydeep/f1wbd9ja/2/) but logic is not completed. Any idea or reference to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create recursive function with `reduce` method to get the desired result.

```js
let data = {"rec":[{"id":"25837","contentId":"25838"},{"id":"25839","contentId":"25838"},{"id":"25838"},{"id":"25636","contentId":"25837"},{"id":"25640","contentId":"25839"}]}

function nest(data, pid) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (pid == e.contentId) {
      const obj = { ...e }
      const children = nest(data, e.id);
      if (children.length) obj.children = children
      r.push(obj)
    }

    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = nest(data.rec);
console.log(result[0])
```